# How to remove local is undeclared prefix error

Tags: xamarin

I am trying to follow this tutorial. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mBlzs5owIEY

I am able to populate a listview with some data, the listview is displaying the correct data when i'm running the emulator.

Could you please explain what is the meaning of the error below?

I want to understand what is causing it, and how do I resolve the issue?

### Error

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error       'local' is an undeclared prefix. Line 7, position 10.       C:\Workspaces\HelloWorld\App1\App1\App1\XAML\ListView.xaml  7
```

### App.xaml

```
using System;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using Xamarin.Forms.Xaml;

namespace App1
{
    public partial class App : Application
    {
        public App()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            MainPage = new ListView();
        }

        protected override void OnStart()
        {
        }

        protected override void OnSleep()
        {
        }

        protected override void OnResume()
        {
        }
    }
}
```

### Debtviewmodel.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;

namespace App1
{
    class DebtViewModel
    {
        public string[] Debt { get; set; }

        public DebtViewModel()
        {
            string[] debt = new string[] { "1", "2", "3" };
            Debt = debt;
        }
    }
}
```

### ListView.xaml

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:d="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms/design"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:App1"
             mc:Ignorable="d"
             x:Class="App1.ListView">

    <!-- Required to map viewmodel -->
    <ContentPage.BindingContext>
        <local:DebtViewModel />
    </ContentPage.BindingContext>

    <!-- Bind variable in view model to listview itemsource -->
    <ContentPage.Content>
        <StackLayout>
            <ListView x:Name="lvDebt" ItemsSource="{Binding Debt}">
                
            </ListView>
        </StackLayout>

    </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

Comment: I think just clearing bin and obj folder in shared and target projects should do the trick

Comment: @rafael I try your code and don't find this error, but I suggest you can clear your error list and try to restart your sample again.